# Dynamic frame resolve choice specs , date cast

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am writing a Glue code and using dynamic frame Api resolve choice , specs . I am trying to cast the source by passing casting when dynamic frame is created from catalog.
I have successfully implemented the casting via resolve choice specs but while casting date i am getting null values , just wanted to understand how can we pass date with source format in casting.
`self.df_TR01=self.df_TR01.resolveChoice(specs=[('col1', 'cast"string'), ('col2_date', 'cast:date')]).toDF()`

But in col2_date i am getting null value and i am trying to understand how can i pass date with source format in the above statement.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered something similar but my issue before when writing dates to Redshift, they were also landing as nulls. In my case, I used the following and it helped me resolve the issue. Maybe this will help.

```
from datetime import datetime

def fix_dates(m):
    m["col2"] = datetime.strptime(m["col2"],  "m/d/yy")
    return m

custommapping1 = Map.apply(frame = datasource0, f = fix_dates, transformation_ctx = "custommapping1")
```

Alternatively you can make use of spark sql, for example:

```
datasource0.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("my_temp_view")

df_cols  = spark.sql("""
  select to_date(cast(unix_timestamp(col2, 'M/d/yy') as timestamp)) as col2 from my_temp_view """)
```

ResolveChoice is normally able to deal with most ambiguities. Can you share a sample date that is failing to cast correctly, maybe I could also try on my end.

Comment: Thanks Eman for the response. I do understand your point but what to use resolvechoice  since i am applying casting at the very first source files.
self.df_TR01=self.df_TR01.resolveChoice(specs=[('col1', 'cast"string'), ('col2_date', 'cast:date')]).toDF()

Comment: Maybe if you share how col2_date looks in terms of values, I could try to get that to work

Comment: it is like 20121202 means year month and date

Comment: My understanding of the DateType in spark is anything supporting "0001-01-01" through "9999-12-31". Anything else you have to work with options that allow you to format the date.

Comment: Yes i am looking for the option to pass source date format via resolveChoice

Comment: Cast will not be able to do it I think, similar my example above. You can use the example below:

`func =  udf (lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%M%d'), DateType())
cast_df = df.withColumn("new_date", func(col('date')))
cast_df.show()
+------+--------+----------+
|  colA|    date|  new_date|
+------+--------+----------+
|     0|20121202|2012-01-02|
|    23|20121202|2012-01-02|`